# What happens when you name a folder as ".."?

Tags: directory, path, macos, mv

Instead of moving a folder to parent directory, I renamed it as ".." using `mv folder_name ..`. Do you have any solution to recover the folder or is it just deleted? (macos 12.4)

Comment: From the command that you show, it seems as if the directory was in fact moved to the parent directory. You have not show any directory listing showing that this is not what happened. It's impossible to create a directory called `..` as that name is already taken. One thing that could possibly confuse things is if you have accessed the current directory via a symbolic link. You don't show whether this is the case though.

Comment: In fact it moved the folder in an expected way. I executed the command from "desktop/folder_a" and was searching for it inside "folder_a" thinking I executed it from desktop/folder_a/folder_b . But it is moved to "desktop". Thank you for your answers. It is a tricky case when you think about it. Glad to learn it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to create a directory or file named `..` because this name is reserved for the parent directory of any directory.

So, the directory was not deleted, you just moved it to the parent, and this is why you don't see it anymore in you current directory.

To move it back to its original place, run

```
mv ../folder_name .
```

Comment: Creating a directory `mkdir ".. "` is no fun anymore with modern implementations of `ls`.